# RuntimeError: cuDNN version mismatch: PyTorch was compiled against 7102 but linked against 7604

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, cudnn

I got this error when running training a deep learning model and although looking at many solutions over the Internet, they did not help me. The log is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 208, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 100, in main
    model = nn.DataParallel(model).cuda()
  File "/home/dexter/miniconda3/envs/VideoSum/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 105, in __init__
    self.module.cuda(device_ids[0])
  File "/home/dexter/miniconda3/envs/VideoSum/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 249, in cuda
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
  File "/home/dexter/miniconda3/envs/VideoSum/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 176, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/dexter/miniconda3/envs/VideoSum/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 112, in _apply
    self.flatten_parameters()
  File "/home/dexter/miniconda3/envs/VideoSum/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 78, in flatten_parameters
    if not any_param.is_cuda or not torch.backends.cudnn.is_acceptable(any_param):
  File "/home/dexter/miniconda3/envs/VideoSum/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/backends/cudnn/__init__.py", line 87, in is_acceptable
    if _libcudnn() is None:
  File "/home/dexter/miniconda3/envs/VideoSum/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/backends/cudnn/__init__.py", line 58, in _libcudnn
    'but linked against {}'.format(compile_version, __cudnn_version))
RuntimeError: cuDNN version mismatch: PyTorch was compiled against 7102 but linked against 7604
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is, no matter the versions showed in the log are, 7.6.4 is my cudnn version and 7.1.2 is the cudnn version that the code is originally compiled. What I need is just downgrade (or upgrade my current cudnn version) by:

```
conda install cudnn=7.1.2
```

It works, if any, please correct me.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me. I was loading bark models on my gcp instance

unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem...downgrading `cudnn` worked for me.  As mentioned here, the error message 
`RuntimeError: cuDNN version mismatch: PyTorch was compiled against 7102 but linked against 7604`

...indicates Pytorch was linked to a newer version of the cudnn library.  It only caused a problem deep in my model. I would guess it was something of an archaic Pytorch function which wasn't updated recently. After downgrading cudnn to the same version as Pytorch, it worked again...no other noticeable loss in performance.

`conda install cudnn=7.1.2`

Sorry to be repetitive, but my StackOverflow rep is too low to add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got over the issue deleting manually old libraries in the
/usr/local/cuda/lib64 folder.